# store form input in a Session variable

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with the variable $_SESSION['number']. The user can set it in the form, but it disappears after they hit Submit! two or more times with the field empty. How can I keep the $_SESSION['number'] after hitting Submit? Thanks

```
<form action=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="number"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>

<?php 

// starting the session
session_start();

$_SESSION['number']=0;

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){ 
    if($_POST['number'] != ''){
        $_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];            
    }

    $_SESSION['number'] = $_SESSION['number'];    
}
echo 'number='.$_SESSION['number'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should like this,

```
<?php
 // starting the session
 session_start();

 $num = 0;

 if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
  if ($_POST['number'] == '') {
    $_SESSION['number'] = $num;
   } else {
    $_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
   }
  echo 'number = '.$_SESSION['number'];
}

?>
 <form action=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

  <input type="text" name="number"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
 </form>
```

And think It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Lakmal, I worked with your code and found that if I set the $_SESSION variable before the *"if else loop"* and keep the *"if else"* logic real simple, It works. The $_SESSION variables work very well for this type of code.

```
<?php
 //starting the session
 session_start();
 $num = 0;

if(!isset($_SESSION['number'])) $_SESSION['number']=0;
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    if($_POST['number'] != ''){
        $_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];
    }
    echo 'number='.$_SESSION['number'];
}
?>
<form action=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="number"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```